# What is the meanings of the input and output parameters of Kalman Filter in WSO2 CEP?

Tags: kalman-filter, wso2-cep

I would like to have some information about the input (named: measuredValue, measuredChangingRate, measurementNoiseSD and timestamp) and output (2 values) of [Kalman Filter Extension](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Kalman+Filter+Extension) in WSO2 CEP 4.2.0. I can't find any kind of documentation.
I suppose that measuredValue is the value to filter, timestamp is a numerical label about the instant of acquisition of measuredValue; and about measuredChangingRate and measurementNoiseSD?
Furthermore I noticed a problem: when I try to use this function, Siddhi says:

> No extension exist for StreamFunctionExtension{namespace='kf'} in execution plan "ExecutionPlan"

Is it possible that there isn't any extension for kalmanFilter function?

My fragment query is that:

```
@Import('InputStream:1.0.0')
define stream InStream (energy double, timestamp long);

define stream ResKalmanFilterStream (energyEstimated double, x double);

from InStream#kf:kalmanFilter(energy)
select *
insert into ResKalmanFilterStream;
```

Comment: Now the Kalman Filter documentation is being updated with parameter descriptions - https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Kalman+Filter+Extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Regarding following error:

> No extension exist for StreamFunctionExtension{namespace='kf'} in
>   execution plan "ExecutionPlan"

`kf:kalmanFilter(energy)` is a function which takes an attribute (`energy` in this case) as a parameter and outputs a new value. In other words, it produces a new attribute, therefore it has to be used in the `select` statement.

```
from InStream
select kf:kalmanFilter(energy) as filteredEnergy
insert into ResKalmanFilterStream;
```

2. Regarding parameters; I could find following information on the parameters in the [Kalman Filter extension source code (refer the class-level comment)](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/v3.1.2/modules/siddhi-extensions/kalman-filter/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/extension/kf/KalmanFilter.java).

> - measuredValue - measured value eg:40.695881
> - measuredChangingRate -
>     Changing rate. eg: Velocity of the point which describes from measured
>     value - 0.003d meters per second
> - measurementNoiseSD - standard
>     deviation of the noise. eg: 0.01
> - timestamp - the timestamp at the
>     measured time eg: 1445234861l